# How to read a file from HDFS in a non-Java client

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

So my MR Job generates a report file, and that file needs to be able to be downloaded by an end-user who needs to click a button on a normal web reporting interface, and have it download the output. According to [this O'Reilly book excerpt](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/456-get-to-know-hadoop-filesystems/), there is an HTTP read-only interface. It says it's XML based, but it seems that it's simply the normal web interface intended to be viewed through a web browser, not something that can be programatically queried, listed, and downloaded. Is my only recourse to write my own servlet based interface? Or execute the hadoop cli tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to access HDFS programmatically from something other than Java is by using Trift.
There are pre-generated client classes for several languages (Java, Python, PHP, ...) included in the HDFS source tree.

See http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HDFS-APIs

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid you will probably have to settle with the CLI AFAIK.

Not sure if it would fit your situation, but I think it would be reasonable to have whatever script that kicks off the MR job do a `hadoop dfs -get ...` after job completion to a known directory that's served.

Sorry that I don't know of an easier solution.

Comment: i think there are thrift/C based libraries in other languages for accessing HDFS